# Using gmm package for R with cross-sectional data

Tags: r

I use a cross-sectional data but would like to use the optimal weight matrix, how to set the arguments so that it gives heteroscedasticity robust variance estimate instead of HAC?

It looks like they only have option between iid and HAC. I don't want to let it waste time to search for dependency.

Comment: Could you provide a reproductible example, it will be more easier to get an answer

Comment: Sorry for not to answer the question, but it's useful to add my observation to this problem. In the example on p.6-9, the author of the package has used the default HAC standard errors in a case with iid data. He then finds in his simulation that the results from GMM is worse than ML and claims that ML uses more information. But indeed, what ML uses is simply the first two moments. I think the inefficiency comes from unnecessarily allowing for auto-correlation. The problem may become more serious when we sort the dependent variable for some other purpose before we feed it into this function.